# Windows Boot Loader doesn't work after upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10 (Windows 8.1 Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, 14.04

I was already running 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1 with no problems at all.  I upgraded to 14.04 LTS yesterday through software updater yesterday and now the Windows boot loader on the Grub menu doesn't work. It just goes black for a second and then returns to the Grub menu again. I should probably add that Windows was pre-installed, so no DVD.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a Linux newcomer, so go easy on me if this is a really obvious fix. I would get rid of Windows entirely but my girlfriend refuses..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just recovered from the same issue. boot from a live-image and install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . just run, reboot, and it fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I didn't use boot repair. Just ignore this and go back to your bios boot menu. Put windows on the top of the list, save, and exit.